# Align Bar Graph with Negative Stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-negative-stack/

```
 xAxis: [{
    categories: categories,
    reversed: false,
    labels: {
        step: 1
    }
}, { // mirror axis on right side
    opposite: true,
    reversed: false,
    categories: categories,
    linkedTo: 0,
    labels: {
        step: 1
    }
}],
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
        }
    }
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    },
    bar : {

    }
},
```

This is the highchart graph I am using. However, I want male bars to start from left and female bars to start from right. Not from the middle.

[This is what I want](https://ibb.co/gd9yBdd)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just two charts placed next to each other. Check demo and code posted below.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
 chart: {
   type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
   text: ''
  },
  credits: {
   enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }],
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
 chart: {
   type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
   text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
   visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
   reversed: true
  },
  series: [{
   color: 'red',
    data: [
      239,
      505,
      511,
      596,
      270,
      199,
      167,
      224
    ]
  }],
});
```

```css
#container1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#container2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5knv49r8/